# How do I stop the MySQL Workbench output area and snippets panel from automatically being hidden?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04, mysql-workbench

I cannot see the output panel and the snippets panel in MySQL Workbench. I submitted a bug to MySQL but it could not be replicated. I got this bug on Ubuntu Linux. It does not happen on Mac. Also, the output panel is not always visible.

This is the bug report. It doesn't tell much though.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a stop-gap solution for this.

The first things to check are the panel icons and the visibility settings under `View -> Panels -> Output Area`.

[Panel Visibility Control Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMnID.png)

If the output panel is still not visible, try to move your mouse to the bottom of the MySQL Workbench window until it turns into a double-headed arrow. Drag upward to reveal the output area. Try the area right below the bottom horizontal scroll bar.

[Possible area to drag up output panel from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybwzG.jpg)

If the `Action Output/Query History` section of that panel is still missing, run a query then try dragging from the bottom of the grid results section.If you cannot find the bottom of the grid results section, run a `SELECT *` query first and try again.

[Workbench action panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3Qb.jpg)

If the side panel for snippets and context help is missing, simply try to drag the rightmost corner of the Workbench window inward.